# Delegate route handlers to other modules in NodeJS+Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been trying to avoid overhead in my routes.js file.

Here's it:

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index')
});

app.get('/contact-us', function(req, res) {
    var col = db.collection('contacts');

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'gmail.user@gmail.com',
            pass: 'userpass'
        }
    });
});
});
}
```

As you can see, this is already becomes flooded by business logic just by instantiating mongo collection and mail transporter. I couldn't find any materials on how to delegate this logic to the outer module, for example, sendmail.js, savetomongo.js etc..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some modification have done by me. I have updated according your requirement.
You need to make it according your actual need.

```
var sendmail = require('./sendmail.js');
var savetomongo = require('./savetomongo.js');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index')
    });

    app.get('/contact-us', function(req, res) {
        var col = db.collection('contacts');
        var document = {'id': 'xyz'};
        savetomongo.save(col, document, function(error, is_save) {
            if (error) {
                //handle error
            } else {
                // next()
                sendmail.sendEmail('DUMMY <from@xyz.com>', 'to@xyz.com', 'TestEmail', 'Only for testing purpose', function(error, isSend) {
                    if (error) {
                        //handle error
                    } else {
                        // next() 
                        //res.render('index')
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
}
```

//sendmail.js

```
module.exports = {
    sendEmail: function(fromEmailFormatted, toEmail, subject, message, fn) {
        var mailOptions = {
            from: fromEmailFormatted, // sender address
            to: toEmail, // list of receivers
            subject: subject, // Subject line
            html: message // html body
        };
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'gmail.user@gmail.com',
                pass: 'userpass'
            }
        });
        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) {
                return fn(error);
            } else {
                return fn(null, true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

//savetomongo.js

```
module.exports = {
    save: function(col, data, fn) {
        col.insert(data, {w: 1}, function(err, records) {
            if (err) {
                return fn(err);
            } else {
                return fn(null, records);
            }
        });
    }
}
```